# How to print number as character in string in C?

Tags: c

Suppose there is number

```
int number;
scanf("%d",&number);
char ch[3];
ch[0]='a';
ch[1]=number;
ch[2]='b'
```

And I want output as a42b (if user input 42 as number) or a43b (if user 
input 43 as number). I don't want the character value of 42 or 43 (means  outputs as a*b or a+b).

Comment: You can't put two characters in one byte. If you want "42" that's the character "4" and the character "2".

Comment: `printf("a%db", number);`. If you just want a character string with the contents, look at `sprintf()` and perhaps `asprintf()`. Remeber that the number of characters required to store your number as a sequence of ASCII chars is potentially pretty large.

Comment: "to print number as character in string" --> `char buf[100]; sprintf(buf, "%c%d%c", ch[0], number, ch[2]); puts(buf);`

Comment: Did you find any of the answers given useful?  If so, feel free to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the answer is that you can't. While you could do the assignment like you do, for values that fit in a `char`, how would you know that it was a number to output and not a character?

The only way I see it is if you know that the second character in the array will *always* be a number and not a character, then you could just print it as a character, a number and a character:

```
printf("%c%d%c\n", ch[0], ch[1], ch[2]);
```

Comment: i dont want to use printf. but i want print whole character string with puts. then how can we print it...suppose there is a string aaaasss and when particular character count is more than 4 we want output string as 4@asss.

Comment: @MOHITMSHARMA Why not?

Comment: @MOHITMSHARMA Then it's not possible.

Comment: If you want to convert a number like 42 into a sequence of characters like "42", you need to use some function to do that: sprintf, itoa, or roll your own. It's not hard--just dividing by 10 and adding 48 in a loop--but you do have to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is `snprintf`, which allows you to do `printf` style formatting and put the results in a string.

```
char ch[10];
int number;
scanf("%d",&number);
snprintf(ch,sizeof(ch),"a%db",number);
```

Comment: @mohit-m-sharma Does this answer your question?